# Maximal commuative subalgebra of $gl(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $gl(n)$ be spanned by $n^2$ abstract operators $\{a_j^i\}$ satisfying the $gl(n)$ commutation relation:

$$[a_j^i,a_l^k] = a^i_l \delta_j^k - a_j^k \delta_l^i$$

Why can we conclude that the subspace of diagonal operators $\{a_k^k\}$ forms a maximal commutative subalgebra?

It's the maximality I am asking about, I *can* see that $[a^j_j,a^k_k]=0,\forall k,j$

I guess lets see if we can put a non-diagonal operator into this, so 
$$[a_j^i,a_l^k] = a^i_l \delta_j^k - a_j^k \delta_l^i,\quad i\ne j,k \ne l$$

We can get $k\ne j,i\ne l$ and it commutes, so $[a_1^2,a_3^4]= a^2_3\delta^4_1-a_1^4\delta_3^2=0$

So yes, why is it the maximal commutative subalgebra

Comment: Note that *everything* must commute with *everything* for the algebra to be commutative. It appears you just found one generator that commutes with the non-diagonal operator, but this does not suffice.

Comment: @Danu Thanks, see my self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maximal because to add another element would require that element to commute with all of the diagonal generators, which we can see that for any $a_j^k$ there is a diagonal operator $a_k^k$(or $a_j^j$ would do) such that we get 
\begin{align}
[a_j^k,a_k^k]=&0\\
\implies& a^k_k\delta^k_j-a_j^k\delta_k^k=0\\
\implies& a^k_k\delta^k_j=a^k_j\delta_k^k=a^k_j
\end{align}
So we obtain that either $a_j^k=0$ or $a_j^k=a^k_k$. In the first case we get a contradiction, since this is one of the $n^2$ generators, and in the latter case we see that it is a diagonal operator.